# composer error when installing spatie media

Tags: laravel

I want to install spatie media library but I get this error while installing:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject> composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^9.0.0"
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update spatie/laravel-medialibrary
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-medialibrary 9.0.0 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-medialibra
ry[9.0.0].
    - spatie/laravel-medialibrary 9.0.0 requires illuminate/bus ^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/bus[v7.0.0, ...,
7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

i didn't have this problem in Laravel 8
how can i fix it?

Comment: Did you try upgrading "illuminate/bus" to "^8.0" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
"composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:*"
```

Comment: what is the problem? why `composer require "spatie/laravel-medialibrary:^9.0.0"
` doesn't work?

Comment: When you use the "*" laravel searches for the most compatible version of your settings.  
I think the reason your way did not work is because your settings might not be up to date, but it can be a lot of reasons.